# Is there a way to identify if there is note or attachment already exists

Tags: apex, attachment, notes

I am trying to copy over notes from account into opportunities. I want to see if there is a same note or attachment already exists in opportunity. i want to copy them over only if the same note doesnt already exists.

Is there a way i can identify if a particular note is already existing? i am not looking for a code but a pseudo code would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you turn the opportunity notes into a set based on the fields you want to check:

```
Set<String> oppSet = new Set<String>();
for (Note n : [select Title, Body from Note where ParentId = :opp.Id]) {
     oppSet.add(n.Title + '::' + n.Body);
}
```

and then filter the account notes:

```
Note[] accNotes = [select Title, Body from Note where ParentId = :acc.Id];
for (Integer i = accNotes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Note n = accNotes[i];
    if (oppSet.contains(n.Title + '::' + n.Body)) {
        accNotes.remove(i);
    }
}
...
```

Using a set here avoids comparing all items in one list against all items in another list as that approach slows down exponentially as the list sizes grow.